# Profile 2 Not showing fields on user edit page

Tags: users

I install Profile 2 module and create separate registration page.
after login with this user 
not showing that fields on edit user page
Can any one help me in this

Comment: What is your Drupal version? Can you see the fields as the administrator? Have you checked the user's permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the permission "[PROFILETYPE]Edit own profile" under "Profile2" section to the respective user roles.

And the fields will be appeared on edit user page.

Comment: this should happen automatically? I'm not getting any profile2 fields on my edit page and those permissions are set.. :/

Comment: even i am having the exact same problem..however in my case the field which are marked as required are displaying but the rest fields are not

Comment: I have the same issue,I want profile 2 fields to appear on the same with other account fields.How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

@theBraveDave - THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!! - I don't have enough "points" to vote-up your answer, but that fixed my problem with profile2.

Specifically:

1. If you're using Panels, check the admin/structure/pages admin page has the /user/%user/edit turned off
2. When editing the profile type (from admin/structure/profiles), make sure "Provide a separate page for editing profiles" is turned off

Then suddenly it started working again. (I'd recently done a Drupal core update plus ctools plus other key modules and suddenly profile2 had stopped working. It appears that somehow the user/edit page was turned back on again and it was as simple as turning it back off ("simple" once I read @theBraveDave's post - thank you!)

-Tom

Answer (score 1):

Using profile2, the first 'main' profile you set up needs to have the box 'Provide a separate page for editing profiles' unchecked on the administration page before it will display on user/[id]/edit forms.

Admin form at /admin/structure/profiles

[image: main profile example]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the problem where I would be on my user edit page and I could see my profile2 profile buttons on the top right. Clicking on them though would just load the same drupal core user/edit page. The profile link was highlighted like I was on that particular profile2 profile edit page, but only the standard core user edit form fields were showing.

I then remembered I was toying around with Drupal Panels and found that I had enabled the Drupal Panels Page- User edit template    /user/%user/edit

I disabled this panel page and then when I clicked on my profile2 profile button from the standard Drupal core user/edit page my Profile2 profile loaded properly. Hope this helps someone.